# How to make page jump work on mobile devices and tablets?

Tags: android, html, ios

So when you have a page jump reference like so:

```
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
```

That jumps down to this bit:

```
<a name="contact"></a>
```

It works fine on computers, however, when I try it on ipad and iphone it's not doing anything. I've searched for countless hours after a solution but I come up with none. Is there a simple fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it by javascript:

```
<li><a href="#" onClick="jump()">Contact</a></li>
```

in jump function you can use jquery or ... to jump. like

```
var position = $("#contact").offset();
$("body").animate({scrollTop: position.top},500);
```

Comment: It scrolls down like 30px, how do I make it so that it scrolls all the way to the bottom?

Comment: you can put any number instead position.top .(like page height)